# Wordpress page permalink No Page Found when using link of deleted page

Tags: wordpress

I have a page that is published. When I go to the page (or even preview it), I get the default Nothing Found page. I used the permalink listed on the Edit Page page, so I am going to the correct link. Furthermore, the page does have content in it.

If I change the permalink to something else (I added an underscore to the end), the page works. However, the permalink that I want does not work. 
I previously had another page at that permalink which I deleted. Also, any subpages of this page have the same problem and are visible if this one is (by the changed permalink).

Comment: sounds like a question for the wordpress forum rather than here unless you can provide code that controls the routing

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check the trash and delete if your deleted page is still there.

Go to settings > permalinks and update your permalink structure.  If you have any caching plugin installed like Wordpress Super Cache or W3 total cache. Please clear the cache.

Now clear your browsers cache or try a different browser just to make sure its not a caching issue.

Sometimes even after deleting a page permanently wordpress keeps the information in database. So first of all backup your wordpress site and database. Then look into the wp_posts table and see if you can find the permalink in post_name column in any row. Deleting the trace of the deleted post from here may solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: I tried all that, but it still does not work. I even deleted the new page and removed it from trash before making it again. It still does not show up.

Comment: Pleas check the answer again. You need to look into the database.